# Divide the rows in a sorted partition into a specific number of groups. [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, sql, divide

I have simple table:

```
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | john   |
|  2 | jane   |
|  3 | philip |
|  4 | robert |
|  5 | clara  |
|  6 | mark   |
|  7 | alex   |
+----+--------+
```

I'd like divide the rows in a sorted partition into a specific number of groups.
I know NTILE function, but my server doesn't support MySQL 8.

This is result desired:

```
 GROUP 1  

+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | john   | 
|  4 | robert | 
|  7 | alex   | 
+----+--------+

 GROUP 2

+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  2 | jane   | 
|  5 | clara  | 
+----+--------+

GROUP 3

+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  3 | philip | 
|  6 | mark   | 
+----+--------+
```

thanks

Comment: Looks like you want to split the result into chunks. Consider to do this in application layer.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel ok then i think i will do it directly through php if doesn't exist a mysql way. thanks

Comment: Have a look at [array_chunk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MOD()` function to do this:

```
select *, mod(id, 3) as group_id from t
```